Python output CSV data as formatted text file
I have an XLSX file which I am using python to convert to CSV to allow me to manipulate using pandas, I would then like to export the data from the CSV file into a formatted text document.
The xlsx data is as follows



Name
Number
Branch Manager




Gustavo Barrett
45
Avery Page


Sterling Lynn
199
Matteo Hicks



I would like the format to be as follows for the TXT file
*****NEW RECORD*****
Name : Gustavo Barrett
Number : 45
Branch Manager : Avery Page
*****RECORD END*****

*****NEW RECORD*****
Name : Sterling Lynn
Number : 199
Branch Manager : Matteo Hicks
*****RECORD END*****

Below is my current code which prints all the names first, then the numbers and the branch managers, it prints them all separately, any idea how i can get it to output in the format i want?
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import time 
with open("waffles.txt", "w") as file:
    filename = 'finals.xlsx'
    df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(filename)) 
    names = df["Name"].to_list()
    numbers = df["Number"].to_list()
    branch = df["Branch Manager"].to_list()
    for i in names:
        for i in names:
            txt_name = "Name : "+str(i)
        for o in numbers:
            txt_number = "Number : "+str(o)
        for a in branch:
            txt_branch = "Branch Manager : "+str(a)
        file.write("\n")
        file.write("*****NEW RECORD*****")
        file.write("\n")
        file.write(i+ "\n")
        file.write(str(o)+ "\n")
        file.write(a+ "\n")
        file.write("*****RECORD END*****")
        file.write("\n")


Please refer to the basics of python.

Is there some sorting problem or what ... you have more for loops then you need.
This should work, with tweaks.
I would suggest to read on some basic string formatting in Python.
import pandas as pd

with open("waffles.txt", "w") as file:
    filename = 'finals.xlsx'
    df = pd.read_excel(filename) 
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        file.write("\n*****NEW RECORD*****\n")
        
        # Adjust it with csv column names
        file.write(f"Name : {row['name']}\n")
        file.write(f"Number : {row['number']}\n")
        file.write(f"Branch Manager : {row['branch manager']}\n")
        file.write("*****RECORD END*****\n")


Thank you, this worked. Going to read up on string formatting in Python now :)
